# How do i get id of the image from gridview and increase hits?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have sql table **Icon(ID(int),ICON_IMAGE(image),hits(int))**
I'm accessing the images in a  gridview. My asp page code looks like this

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
 <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
  <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "imagehandler.ashx?ID=" + Eval("ID")%>'/>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ICOBANKConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ICON_IMAGE], [ID] FROM [Icon]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

imagehandler.ashx code is like this

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ICOBANKConnectionString"].ConnectionString;



    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  ICON_IMAGE FROM  Icon WHERE (ID = @ID)";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    SqlParameter ImageID = new SqlParameter("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    ImageID.Value = context.Request.QueryString["ID"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageID);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dReader.Read();
    context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dReader["ICON_IMAGE"]);
    dReader.Close();
    con.Close();
```

Its working fine. Now problem is i'm trying to get the id of the image to display it on other page and also increase the hits when someone clicks on the image. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a simple way:**

```
protected void grdView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

{
    if (e.CommandName == "selectImage")
    {

        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); // Get the current row
        int cellVal = Convert.ToInt32(grdView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Text);//Get the cell value

        Response.Write(cellVal.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: **selectImage** I can't understand it?